# Number of prime knots with n crossings

Tags: code-golf, sequence, combinatorics, topology, knot-theory

A [prime knot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_knot) is:

> a non-trivial knot which cannot be written as the knot sum of two non-trivial knots.

Explanation of a [knot-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum#Connected_sum_of_knots): put the two knots adjacent,

[image]

... then draw two lines between them, to the same strand on each side, and remove the part between the lines you just drew. This composition of two knots will form a new, non-prime knot.

[image]

Here are all prime knots with 7 or fewer crossings (the Unknot is not prime):

[image]

You need to output the number of unique prime knots for a given number of crossings.

```
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1
5   2
6   3
7   7
8   21
9   49
10  165
11  552
12  2176
13  9988
14  46972
15  253293
16  1388705
```

I don't think the values are known for inputs larger than `16`, but if given such an input, your code would need to find the correct result given enough time.

[OEIS - A002863](http://oeis.org/A002863)

Comment: Perhaps someone will find [this Mathematica library](http://katlas.org/wiki/Setup) useful.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica + [KnotTheory`](http://katlas.org/wiki/Setup), 13 bytes

```
NumberOfKnots
```

I didn't know this built-in function existed when I commented that the package might be useful. Everyone else had an equal chance to find it, since I commented about the library. I found it in the list of [Lightly Documented Features](http://katlas.org/wiki/Lightly_Documented_Features). Still, I won't accept this answer, since I want to see answers by other people.

Comment: Seeing as the documentation is very poor are you sure this works for numbers greater than 16?

Comment: @WheatWizard No, I'm not sure how to tell. It would take way too long to run to completion. Is there a way to find out how it's implemented?

Comment: Have you tried running it?  It might just return an error.  I can't run mathematica right now but I would check if it stalls when you attempt to run it.

Comment: @WheatWizard I can't check either. Let me know if you try it.

Comment: I actually looked through the source code for a bit, searching for it, but I didn't find the definition. The repository is publicly available. http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/svn/KnotTheory/trunk/KnotTheory/